# My CallerId is not revealed when using Internet Calling (VoIP) on ICS

Tags: voip, caller-id

I configured my VoIP account with ICS Internet Calls, so I can call over WiFi using a VoIP account. However call receivers don't get my Caller ID, instead it comes up as withheld/unknown number.

There are some additional fields in Internet Calling that I haven't populated.

Is it part of the SIP protocol to pass the Caller ID and can it be configured?

P.S.: When I use VoIP program from my VoIP provider, I can configure Caller ID.

Comment: Have you tried calling from your voip account using a computer or other client? From what I know, SIP clients simply register themselves with the server, and the server itself determines whether caller id is sent. So I doubt Android is the cause of the missing id, since it is just a client.

Comment: @dymutaos Yes I have tried other clients on Android and PC, but my question really is - whether sending CID is part of SIP protocol, and if so Android just doesnt expose this field in its UI ??